# Rails 4, create links in popover from array

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have Users who can recommend other Users' profiles (don't worry about the models & associations, they work fine), and I can see which users recommended the current_user's profile by using current_user.profile.recommended_by in the console.  What I want to do is create a "link" (that goes nowhere) that when I click on it displays a popover which shows the names of each person who recommended the current_user and links to the profile page of each recommender.

I have a popover function (from Twitter Bootstrap) that works fine with static stuff

profile.html.erb

```
   ......
    Recommended by <%= link_to "#{current_user.profile.recommended_by.count} users", "#", id: "example", datacontainer: "body", datatoggle:"popover", dataplacement:"right", title: "static stuff" %>
    .......
```

I think what I want is to pass a dynamic array to "title:"? I have no idea how to do this.

profile.html.erb

```
 ...........
<% current_user.profile.recommended_by.each do |r| %>
    <% r.first_name => array1 %>
        <% r.last_name => array1%>
    <% end %>

 Recommended by <%= link_to "#{current_user.profile.recommended_by.count} users", "#", id: "example", datacontainer: "body", datatoggle:"popover", dataplacement:"right", title: :array1 %>
.......................
```

As you can probably tell, I'm new to Ruby on Rails & web dev, any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

Update

I figured out how  to pass the arrays:

PagesController

```
  def page

@recusers = current_user.profile.recommended_by
@recnames = @recusers.collect do |recuser| 
  recuser.first_name + " "+ recuser.last_name[0]
 end 

end
```

When I pass @recnames to "title:" it displays  the names as I want them to! But how do I make it link to the profile page of each?

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than I thought:

profile.html.erb

```
................
Recommended by <%= link_to  "#{current_user.profile.recommended_by.count} users", "#", id: "example", datacontainer: "body", datatoggle:"popover", dataplacement:"right", "data-content" => "#{@recnames.map{|a, b| link_to a, profile_path(b)}.join(', ')}" %>
...............
```

PagesController

```
  def den

@recusers = current_user.profile.recommended_by
@recnames = @recusers.collect do |recuser| 
  [recuser.first_name + " "+ recuser.last_name[0], recuser.profile]
end 


end
```